# Print out the index of elements in a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell programming and I am trying to write a program that prints out the index of elements in a list.

Here is the code I have:

```hs
Index :: [Int]->[Int]

Index []= []
Index(x:xs)= 0:index (xs+1)
```

Comment: What's your desired output for list [1,5,10,13] ?

Comment: Why are you capitalising `Index`? Only data values start with capital letters.

Comment: @peace: not sure what you're asking, and I think you should be spending a couple of days reading a Haskell tutorial/book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is unclear, and no effort to improve it by the asker has been made in over 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the following?

```
index :: [a] -> [Int]
index x = [1 .. length x]
```

`[1..4]` is shorthand for `[1,2,3,4]`...

Comment: Maybe with a `zip`? That might be what we're looking for... as in `index :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]`.